# Symfony FOSRest ChoiceType

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm trying to submit a form with FOSRest. So far so good, but I would just like to know which format the choiceType accepts? Is it an associative Array? Or ..?

FormType

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name', TextType::class);
    $builder->add('roles', ChoiceType::class, [
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true
    ]);
}
```

Submitted Data:

```
{"group":{"name":"esdfgh","roles":["ROLE_VIEW_ALL_CATEGORIES","ROLE_ADD_RECEIPTS","ROLE_EDIT_RECEIPTS","ROLE_VIEW_ALL_RECEIPTS"]}}
```

But that gives the error: "This value is not valid" on the ChoiceType.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide valid [choices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choices)

> The choices option is an array, where the array key is the item's
>   label and the array value is the item's value

According to your example, should be something like this:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name', TextType::class);
    $builder->add('roles', ChoiceType::class, [
        'choices' => [
         "ROLE_VIEW_ALL_CATEGORIES" => "ROLE_VIEW_ALL_CATEGORIES",
         "ROLE_ADD_RECEIPTS" => "ROLE_ADD_RECEIPTS"
        ]
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true
    ]);
}
```